# How to get a a property value by reference using reflection in PHP?

Tags: php, reflection

Suppose you have a class declared like this:

```
class DummyObject{
    public $attr;
    public function __construct(){
        $this->attr=array('val_1','val_2','val_3');
    }
}
```

Doing this:

```
$obj=(new DummyObject1());
$attr=&$obj->attr;
```

You'll get a reference to `$attr` so any modifications made in the array will be made also in DummyObject $obj instance.

And now, finally the question. Using reflection, ¿how can I get a reference to the array stored in `$attr` and not a copy?. I've tried this without success:

```
$obj=(new DummyObject());
$reflector = new ReflectionObject($obj);
$reflectorProperty = $reflector->getProperty('attr');
$propertyValue=$reflectorProperty->getValue($ref);
```

In fact,`$attr` is a copy of original array.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: May I ask what your intention is? I mean, you have the object, the property name and the property is public. Why do you need to use reflection to get hold of the property?

Comment: The only intention I can guess is to make code be complicate.

Comment: My intention it isn't make code complicated.
I have an object, wich can have references to others objects, adquired from an HTTP response in JSON using json_decode and i need to run through all properties recursively to make some changes in all the attributes storing strings.

Comment: There is probably an easier way to do this, can you show the json code?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since PHP 5.4 you can do this without reflection:

```php
class Kitchen
{
    private $yummy = 'cake';
}

$reader = function & ($object, $property) {
    $value = & Closure::bind(function & () use ($property) {
        return $this->$property;
    }, $object, $object)->__invoke();

    return $value;
};

$kitchen = new Kitchen();
$cake    = & $reader($kitchen, 'yummy');
$cake    = 'sorry, I ate it!';

var_dump($kitchen);
```

This is thanks to the ability of PHP 5.4 to switch the scope of a closure at runtime.

You can find a running example at http://3v4l.org/sZMt1

I actually explained the technique and eventual use cases in detail at http://ocramius.github.io/blog/accessing-private-php-class-members-without-reflection/

Comment: Is there any reason why you made the outer function a closure too? It seems to be unnecessary. https://3v4l.org/4tAqu

Comment: I just noticed this does not work for "internal" classes. Obviously. https://3v4l.org/2BZRg "Warning: Cannot bind closure to scope of internal class ReflectionClass", "Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function __invoke() on null"

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid you can't. `ReflectionProperty::getValue` would have to return by reference for that to be possible, which it doesn't.

Comment: I suspected that. But i've noticed that `ReflectionProperty::getValue` returns references if that value is an associative array or another object, so maybe could be a way of retrieving arrayas references in the same way.

Comment: @jLu I don't know what you mean. From what I can see getValue can never return references.

Comment: I've tried with attributes pointing to object instances and associatives arrays and then `ReflectionProperty::getValue` returns references because changes in the returned objects can be seen in original object. This behaviour is not the same when the attribute points to an array.
Thanks for your interest!

Answer (score 0):

You can get it from original $obj that you can pass to callback via "use" statement

```
$propertyValue = $obj->{$reflectorProperty->getName()};
```

Or if you use public getters/setters for private members you can

```
$propertyName = $reflectorProperty->getName();
$methodName = 'get' . ucfirst($propertyName);
if (method_exists($obj, $methodName)) {
    $propertyValue = call_user_func([ $object, $methodName ]);
} elseif (isset($obj->{$propertyName}) {
    $propertyValue = $this->{$propertyName};
} else {
    $propertyValue = null;
}
```

Another solution is to define private (or public) method $obj->getProperty($name) and call it from your callback through reflection and setAccessible. As soon as this method defined in original class it has access to all private members.